# Cross-banding with CSS in HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following effect:

[image: Cross bands]

The HTML I have to work with is a simple table:

```
<table id="a">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

In order to get the rounded borders, I have to change `td` elements to display as `inline-block`.

My problem lies in the grey bands. I end up with white-space between rows. I can't use a separate background element because the number of rows will change. **edit:** *I need the spacing between borders, but want the white gaps in the grey column to be grey too...*

My attempts are here: https://jsfiddle.net/h5Lh1eaw/24/

Is there magic CSS to do this that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to get the gaps as you want is to wrap the tbody cell content in a span

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

table {
  border-spacing:6px 0;  /* gap between columns */
}

td {
  padding: 3px 0;       /* gap between rows */
  width: 200px;
}
thead td,
tfoot td {
  padding:3px;         /* match padding of span */
}

tbody td > span {
  padding:3px;        
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td > span:after {           /* border gap filler */
  content:'';
  display:block; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:100%;
  top:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
  width:6px;                             /* match border spacing size */
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:first-child > span {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:last-child > span:after {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="a">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>normal</span></td>
      <td><span>grey</span></td>
      <td><span>grey</span></td>
      <td><span>normal</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>normal</span></td>
      <td><span>grey</span></td>
      <td><span>grey</span></td>
      <td><span>normal</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Using pseudo elements for borders instead of spans

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

table {
  border-spacing:6px 0;  /* gap between columns */
}

td {
  width: 200px;
}
thead td,
tfoot td {
  padding:3px;         /* match padding of span */
}

tbody td {
  padding: 6px 3px;       /* 6px is so that we have vertical padding */
  position: relative;
}

tbody td:after {           /* borders */
  content:'';
  display:block; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0;
  right: -6px;              /* match border spacing size */
  top:3px;                  /* half the vertical padding */
  bottom:3px;             
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:first-child:after {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:last-child:after {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  right: -3px;                     /* not sure if you want this to poke out the end of the table */
}
```

```html
<table id="a">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pete! First prize would be a CSS-only solution, but I do have some control over the content of the table, so this might be a viable solution for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Pete I told you right, it's not possible directly, but you can do it using this way. Yeah, anyway, happy that you got it solved. `:D`

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you, @Pete

Answer (score 2):

Yep! You have to give `border-collapse: collapse` to the `<table>` and you have:

**CSS**

```css
table#a, table#b {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]

**Snippet**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table#a {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table#b {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

tbody tr {
  margin: 5px;
}

td {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 200px;
}

tbody td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>
  A:
</p>
<table id="a">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  B:
</p>
<table id="b">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>normal</td>
      <td>grey</td>
      <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/gfqrL8n0/

Comment: but it gets rid of the space between the borders and not only the gray background of the elements.

Comment: @Jeremy Ah! So the space should be there as well? Lemme correct it.

Comment: I am not sure, but his example image has that.

Comment: @Jeremy Gotcha... Lemme try fiddling around to get that effect. Meanwhile if the OP is happy with the solution, let him speak. `:)`

Comment: @Jeremy And thanks for the heads-up / clarification.

Comment: I need the space between the borders, but no white gaps in the "grey" column. Thanks, @PraveenKumar  - and sorry about not expressing that clearly.

Comment: @Philip I have tried everything, even something with [`colgroup`](http://jsbin.com/keheyeqoma/1/edit). It looks like it's not possible. I am trying to find if there's anything else possible. Have a look at the [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/keheyeqoma/1/edit) anyway.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I once did something like this accidentally with (I think)  `display: table-cell` I tried to find it but can't find it anymore. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: @Jeremy We can do it using other elements. Like completely removing the `<table>` and using `<div>` or `<ul>` and `<li>` - giving the table cell styles.

Answer (score -1):

Check this CSS:

```
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    table#a {
        border-spacing: 5px, 0;
    }

    table#b {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
        background-color: #c0c0c0;
        border-right: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    }

    td:nth-child(1) {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    tbody tr {
        margin: 5px;
    }

    td {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 3px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    tbody td {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    tbody td:first-of-type {
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
    }

    tbody td:last-of-type {
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
```

---

check the image snippet

[image]